# readint function help... ?(MASM)

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to complete a MASM program. This is my goal (my homework).

Modify the Summation program in Section 5.6.1 (pages 173-175) as follows: Select an array size using a constant:

ARRAY_SIZE = 20

array DWORD ARRAY_SIZE DUP(?)

Write a new procedure that prompts the user for the number of integers to be processed.  Pass the same to the PromptForIntegers procedure. For example,

How many integers will be added? 5

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
 array_size = 10
 .data
 prompt1 byte "How many integers will be added?", 0
 prompt2 byte "Enter a signed integer: ", 0
 prompt3 byte "The sum of the integers is: ", 0
 array dword array_size dup(?)
 .code
 main proc
        call clrscr
        mov ecx,eax
        call promptMes
        call arraysum
        call displaysum
        exit
main endp
promptMes proc uses ecx edx esi
        mov edx,offset prompt1
        mov esi,offset array
        call writestring        
        call readint            
        call crlf               
        call promptforintegers
        ret
promptMes endp
promptforintegers proc uses ecx edx esi
    mov edx,offset prompt2      
    l1: call writestring        
    call readint            
    call crlf               
    mov [esi], ax               
    add esi,type word       

        loop l1
        ret
promptforintegers endp
arraysum proc uses esi ecx
    mov eax, 0                      
    l1: add eax,[esi]               
    add esi,type dword              
    loop l1         
    ret                         
arraysum endp
    mov edx, offset prompt3         
    call writestring
    call writeint               
    call crlf
    ret
displaysum endp
end main
```

My problems are that my counter continues to iterates infinite times, and my question is how and where do I take the user input above (5) and pass the counter and (5) to procedure promptForIntegers?

I saw the [same question](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/assembly/threads/396080/procedure) online, and this is the reply that they got.

> where is the function readint ?
>
> How is ecx set to the number of integers that the user wants? Maybe
>   its set in readint?

However, they did not show the source of the code complete. And I do not know how to modify my code using the readint. Can anyone tell me how this will look like with the readint function?

Answer (score 0):

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
array_size = 10
.data
prompt1 byte "How many integers will be added?", 0
prompt2 byte "Enter a signed integer: ", 0
prompt3 byte "The sum of the integers is: ", 0
array dword array_size dup(?)
.code
main proc
    call clrscr
    mov ecx,eax
    call promptMes
    call arraysum
    call displaysum
    exit
main endp
promptMes proc uses ecx edx esi
    mov edx,offset prompt1
    mov esi,offset array
    call writestring        
    call readint            
    call crlf               
    call promptforintegers
    ret
promptMes endp
promptforintegers proc uses ecx edx esi
mov edx,offset prompt2      
l1: call writestring        
call readint            
call crlf               
mov [esi], ax               
add esi,type word       

    loop l1
    ret
promptforintegers endp
arraysum proc uses esi ecx
mov eax, 0                      
l1: add eax,[esi]               
add esi,type dword              
loop l1         
ret                         
arraysum endp
mov edx, offset prompt3         
call writestring
call writeint               
call crlf
ret
displaysum endp
end main
```

Comment: While ths code may solve the amswer, it's always better if you can provide a description on how the code solves the issue.